# Excel function using "Vlookup or IF or Match"

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to compare two databases.

I have extracted the data from both DBs.

Database A has hundreds of Employee Names(A2) and their Employee IDs (C2) Sheet Called 'Hold'

Database B has a few dozen Employee Names and their Employee IDs (A2) Sheet Called "Table"

I need to find those that match, preferably highlighting the matches with Color #FBF719

Manager looks at the colors, not-so-much the data. I know this is Excel 101 but I have searched for two days and all formulas do not work

I am seeking a maths explanation in simple terms.

Examples:

```
=IF(Hold!B2,[@[Employee ID]],Table!A2,[@[Employee ID]])
=VLOOKUP(Hold!B2, Table!$C:$D, 2, False)
[COLOR=#FBF719]=VLOOKUP(C2,Hold!A2:A29726,[/COLOR][COLOR=#ff0000]Table!B:B[/COLOR][COLOR=#FBF719],FALSE)[/COLOR]
```

I either end up with '0' or 'Value' but not one match

Comment: Formulas do not see formatting, nor can they by themselves set formatting.  You will want to use `Conditional Formatting`, in which you can use a formula that returns TRUE/FALSE to set the formatting.

Comment: Maybe a better suggestion is to return TRUE or FALSE in another column and filter on that. No need to scroll to the colored values.